# How does this js snippet work?

Tags: javascript

```
function thunkify(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 );
    return function(cb) {
        args.push( cb );
        return fn.apply( null, args );
    };
}
```

so `[]` returns an Array object. then `slice.call` creates a new array with the contents of the arguments starting from 1 if i'm right.

but then how does function(cb) work? it where do you get the cb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function(cb) { ... }` creates a function.

`cb` is the argument passed to it.

You get it when the function is called.

```
var thunkified = thunkify(someFunction);
thunkified("the value of cb");
```

Answer (score 2):

args is now an array holding all thunkify args (except the first one as you said).
that args array, than gets a cb function pushed every time the returned function is called (thats closure, the returned function has access to the args from the thunkify function).

`var myfn = thunkify(fn, 1, 2, 3); //now args is [1, 2, 3];
myfn(4); //now args is [1, 2, 3, 4] and fn is called with that array`